# SQL - Replace first instance of value after specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to replace the value associated with a specific key in a string.

For example, I have a string like this:

```
'{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "KeyToUpdate":"ValueToUpdate", "Key3":"Value3", "Key4":"Value4"}'
```

There will be a key called `KeyToUpdate`. It will always be unique and will always be surrounded by quotes. I then need to update it's corresponding value. i.e. The first string found after the colon that is surrounded by quotes. In this example, the value is `ValueToUpdate`. Again, the colon delimiter is always there and the value will always be surrounded in quotes.

My expected output, if i updated the value to `UpdatedValue` would be:

```
'{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "KeyToUpdate":"UpdatedValue", "Key3":"Value3", "Key4":"Value4"}'
```

My question is:

1. How can I achieve this query in a more concise/clean way
2. How can the query be altered to be performed on all rows in a column.

Here is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(256) = '{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "KeyToUpdate":"ValueToUpdate", "Key3":"Value3", "Key4":"Value4"}'

DECLARE @KeyToFind VARCHAR(256) = '"KeyToUpdate":"'
DECLARE @LengthOfKeyToFind INT = LEN(@KeyToFind)

DECLARE @StartIndex INT = PATINDEX('%'+@KeyToFind+'%',@Value)
DECLARE @EndIndex INT =  CHARINDEX('"',SUBSTRING(@Value,@StartIndex + @LengthOfKeyToFind, LEN(@Value))) -1

SELECT STUFF(@Value, @StartIndex + @LengthOfKeyToFind, @EndIndex, 'UpdatedValue')
```

Comment: Where does that string come from? It seems strange that you have a DBMS where you could simply have a key-value table and the update would be super-simple, but instead you are dealing with a string that you try to parse. Such string manipulation would probably be much easier outside the DBMS with a real programming language instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is a one off script (bug fix) that needs to be applied to a single table. The data is simply 'logging' data that we need to store and therefore is used for read only purposes. It cannot and should not be stored as anything else in the DBMS.

Comment: Maybe you can parse your json and then modify. Take a look at this: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: @RicardoPontual Thanks. I had seen this, although it seemed overkill for such a specific scenario I have. Essentially I'm treating this as a string manipulation exercise rather than having JSON that needs parsing.

Comment: You can encapsulate your current query in a UDF that can be used in an UPDATE command to process all rows in a table.   But if this is a one-off, I'd sooner run a cursor-based script, throw it away and forget it ever happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UDF to return the updated column value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UpdateKeyValue(@Value NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                                   @KeyToFind NVARCHAR(100), 
                                   @ValueToUpdate NVARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pattern NVARCHAR(105) = '%"'+@KeyToFind+'":"%'
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT = PATINDEX(@pattern, @Value)

    -- A little defensive coding
    IF @StartIndex = 0 RETURN @Value

    DECLARE @EndIndex INT =  CHARINDEX('"', @Value, @StartIndex + LEN(@pattern))

    RETURN STUFF(@Value, 
                 @StartIndex + LEN(@pattern) - 2, 
                 @EndIndex - (@StartIndex + LEN(@pattern) - 2),
                 @ValueToUpdate)
END
```

And then use it in an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE 
  SET column = dbo.UpdateKeyValue(column, N'KeyToFind', N'UpdatedValue')
FROM
  table
WHERE
  column LIKE '%"KeyToFind":"%'
```

edit: I spent so much time formatting my answer that my ship passed Tab Alleman's comment in the ether. His comment about a throwaway cursor makes good one-off sense.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a one-off transformation, this should work.

```
declare @start int = (select charindex('"KeyToUpdate"', colname) + len('"KeyToUpdate"') + 1 from tablename)
declare @numchars int = (select charindex(',', 
                        substring(colname, charindex('"KeyToUpdate"', colname) + len('"KeyToUpdate"') + 1, len(colname)) - 1 from tablename)
declare @before varchar(255) = (select substring(colname, 1, charindex('"KeyToUpdate"', colname) - 2) from tablename)
declare @after varchar(255) = (select substring(colname,  @start+@numchars+1, len(colname)) from tablename)

select @before + substring(colname, @start, @numchars) + @after 
from tablename
```